# Multiple checkbox with 2 running totals

Tags: javascript, html

I got some help here the other day with a running total based on selecting multiple checkboxes and subtracting a discount for choosing more than 1 service. Is it possible to display the actual total and below the discounted total

Example:
[X] - option 1 = $50 
[X] - option 2 = $50 
[ ] - Option 3 = $50 
[ ] - Option 4 = $50 
Actual total = $100 
Discounted total = $75

Code as follows:

```
 <script>
 function checkTotal() {
    document.listForm.total.value = '';
    var sum = 0;        var o = 0;
    for (i=0;i<document.listForm.choice.length;i++) {
      if (document.listForm.choice[i].checked) {
        sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice[i].value);
          o++;
      }
    }
 if (o>1) {sum=sum-25;}
 document.listForm.total.value = sum;

}
</script>
<form name="listForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="50" onChange="checkTotal()"/>Back Massage - 30 Minutes<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="50" onChange="checkTotal()"/>Neck Massage - 30 minutes<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="50" onChange="checkTotal()"/>Shoulder Massage - 30 Minutes<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="30" onChange="checkTotal()"/>Head Massage - 15 minutes<br/>
 Total: 
<input type="text" size="2" name="total" value="0"/>
</form>
```

Comment: why dont you set the total = sum before doing `if( o>1)` ?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the suggestion. I had a go at that but wasn't successful. Is it something simple. I.e.  document.listForm.total.value = sum;  if (o>1) {sum=sum-25;}. Please excuse my ignorance. I really appreciate the help.